# Como calcular dias, ignorando as horas?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, data

Como posso calcular se passou 1 dia, ignorando as horas. Explicando, seria mais ou menos assim:

Tenho uma data `2017-09-09 11:45:20`, normalmente se teria passado 1 dia, quando chegasse as *11:45* do outro dia, porém eu gostaria que contasse como 1 dia assim que desse `00:00:00`.

Mesmo eu tendo a seguinte data `2017-09-09 23:59:59` e agora fosse `2017-09-10 00:00:00`. Literalmente se passou apenas **1 minuto**, mas eu quero que conte como **1 dia**.

> Eu tentei fazer da seguinte maneira, mas me retornou 0:

```
//                          mês/dia/ano hora:min:seg
// questData.CompletedDate   09/09/2017 11:45:20
// DateTime.Today            09/10/2017 00:00:00
int totalDays = (int)DateTime.Today.Subtract(questData.CompletedDate).TotalDays;
```

Como fazer isso em C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta pegar só a parte de dias com a propriedade [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) do `DateTime`.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine((new DateTime(2017, 09, 10, 11, 45, 00).Date - new DateTime(2017, 09, 09, 11, 45, 20).Date).TotalDays);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XdWMsa). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UuBP9D). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DifferenceIgnoreHours.cs).